# What's the meaning of 間時肆拾貳 at a car parking sign

Tags: translation

I'm trying to translate this car parking sign/garage and I'm stuck on the part for **間時肆拾貳**

[image]

Google just returns the translation "In between", so I still don't know what they mean. Maybe it's like parking in between the lines?

Comment: Is this easy to read for native speakers (especially when being distracted by driving)? Seems like a readability nightmare...

Comment: @Darius As long as anime doesn't become so overly popular that they start putting up signs like this in real life, we should be OK.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is a tricky one because this sign is 1) written right-to-left, 2) using kanji for numbers, and 3) using **old**/**traditional** kanji for the numbers.

So rearranging it left-to-right and using simplified kanji would give us

> (top) [時間貸]{じ・かん・かし}　→　Hourly Rental / Pay by-the-hour
>   (right, red) [五十M先]{ご・じゅう・メートル・さき}　[入口]{いり・ぐち}　→　Entrance (is) 50 meters ahead
>   (example in question) [二十四時間]{に・じゅう・よ・じ・かん}　→　(Open) 24 Hrs.
>   (lower left, green) [空車]{くう・しゃ}　→　Vacancy / Empty spaces availabe

- [Here is a reference to kanji used for numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_numerals#Formal_numbers).

Comment: Isn't the text actually in Chinese?

Comment: @EiríkrÚtlendi 時間 doesn't mean *hour* in Chinese, it means *time* - as in, "Do you have *time*?". I assure you that most of the sign's vocabulary would be unnatural if read in Chinese, although most of us can interpret it without any issue.

Comment: @istrasci thanks! yea it makes sense now ;)

Comment: @droooze: Very interesting.  A quick scan of the red text didn't parse as Japanese, and the 镸 radical in 肆 looks like a non-Japanese simplification of 長, hence my guess at Chinese.

Comment: @EiríkrÚtlendi 镸 is the left-side combining form of 長. Refer to the top left hand component of 髪. (Simplified Chinese reduces 長 to 长, but the character 肆 was unaffected; I don't really know why.)

Comment: @istrasci Unfortunately, I could not understand the meaning. It's not obvious for me yet :( 
Could you please add the meaning in your answer for others as well who are like me :)

Comment: @droooze, FWIW, [時間貸 does appear as a contiguous string in Chinese](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22%E6%99%82%E9%96%93%E8%B2%B8%22+%22%E6%98%AF%22) (traditional, probably Taiwanese or Hong Kong), though presumably meaning something like "time loan" rather than "hourly rental".  也我會看也説就一點兒的中國話。 (Although I'm sure my phrasing and vocab are crap anymore. :) )

Comment: @tod:  Updated.  There you go.

Comment: @EiríkrÚtlendi Unfortunately not! It's a contiguous string but not a contiguous phrase. The parsing for that first result is: "不同" (*a different*) "時間" (*time*) "貸放" (*loan*, but in a financial sense only). The string means: *loaning money [to a customer] at different times to X*. Also, nice try on the Chinese, but unfortunately it didn't turn out sensible haha :)

Comment: @droooze, fair enough.  :)  我的中國話能力太低了。

Answer (score 2):

It means "24 hours".

First of all, the pic is wrong side out.
Second, it is Japanese not Chinese（I mean the language not the characters).
Japanese use a lot traditional Chinese characters.
Third, it is an ad for parking lot and cars.

so, in the turns it was supposed to be:

時間貸⇒For rent by hour
(時間means hour in Japanese but time in Chinese)

伍拾M先⇒50 meters ahead
(this can be a very old ad,coz modern Japanese use 五十,伍拾 is traditional Chinese even in mainland china people are not using it in daily life, but in taiwan they still do)

贰拾肆時間⇒24 hours(means for rent for 24h of course)
(same as above, it can be very old, i can ensure you many japanese people can not read this,they use 二十四時間 now, but they used to use traditional ones before)

空車⇒available car 
(usually used on taxi to let people know that that cab is available)

*Can not believe it my first answer is about this.